# How to Compare content of two data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

Given are the two data frames A and B, where A is longer than B.
The values ​​in the lines of A must be present in lines of B.
And if a line of A does not exist in B, it should be deleted.
At the end A should have the same lines like B.
Do I Need a for-loop?
Thanks for your help, I hope I illustrated the problem well.

## for example:

````
x=c(1,3,7,1,1,4,3)
y=c(2,5,5,6,2,6,4)
A<-cbind.data.frame(x,y)

x2<-c(1,3,5,1,3)
y2<-c(2,4,7,6,8)
B<-cbind.data.frame(x2,y2)



##A should like this at the end
```
x<-c(1,1,1,3)
y<-c(2,6,2,4)
A<-c(x,y)
```
````

Comment: Something like: `merge(A, B, by.x = c("x", "y"), by.y = c("x2", "y2"))`

Comment: @RonakShah it is a dupe, I was just trying to find the right one.

Comment: If you need to keep the order after merging, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17878291/680068).

Comment: you could do `merge(B, A, by.x = names(B), by.y = names(A))`

Answer (score 1):

Something I have used in the past:

```
i = interaction(A,sep=":")%in%interaction(B,sep=":")
i
TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

A[i,]
  x y
1 1 2
4 1 6
5 1 2
7 3 4
```

What is done here is join columns with a symbol you are sure not to encounter in your data (`:`) and then compare these two vectors. It has saved me lots of time.

Comment: thank you! works this for decimal values too?

Comment: yep it should also work

Comment: @review read about [merging with decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40183163/680068), you might want to round the numbers before merging. Also relevant post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal